# Part=statistics - viewCount

Tags: api, youtube, statistics, youtube-data-api

I previously used a query of the form
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&key=MY_KEY&part=statistics
The answer was the point "viewCount".
Now it is not displayed

Comment: statistics is still working. might have been an issue with the api. If you still having problems, then check your code. Only thing I can see though is the order in which you have made the calls.

Comment: its working, but item "viewCount" havent in the response. ist show only this
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Ag26Kx2YnV9iVomHgDa0uyuPCCo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/IhAWYmFMtTHqFXQdX6ZQ1H8stE4\"",
   "id": "5aicsZVARCc"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: There seems to be an issue with some videos and the api at the moment I think. Many have been having same issue. Best to put a bug report into youtube/google.

Comment: If you haven't seen it already: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37107133

Comment: I knew that I'm not a fool) Thanks!